# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

Whenever I run this, the `chooseCave()` function works fine with the `in.nextInt()`. When I choose the cave, the messages pop up at 2-second intervals, and then as soon as it gets past that part, it gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Dragon.main(Dragon.java:81)
```

I have tried `hasNextLine()` and `hasNextInt()`, and when I use `while hasNextLine()` in the `main` method, I get a ton more errors. When I use `while hasNextInt()` in the `chooseCave()` method, it doesn't accept my input.

When I use `if hasNextInt()` in the `chooseCave()` method, it doesn't accept my input for the `playAgain` string, and goes straight into another game, but then the `hasNextInt()` boolean returns `false` and it spams "Which cave..." infinitely.

I've gone through the error reports and the Java-docs and Stack Overflow's with similar problems. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dragon {

public static void displayIntro() {
    System.out.println("You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you, ");
    System.out.println("You see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly");
    System.out.println("and will share his treasure with you. The other dragon");
    System.out.println("is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight");
    System.out.println(' ');
}

public static int chooseCave() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cave = 0;
    while (cave != 1 && cave != 2) {
        System.out.println("Which cave will you go into? (1 or 2)");

        cave = in.nextInt();

    }
    in.close();
    return cave;
} 

public static void checkCave(int chosenCave) {
    System.out.println("You approach the cave...");
    try
       {
       // Sleep at least n milliseconds.
       // 1 millisecond = 1/1000 of a second.
       Thread.sleep( 2000 );
       }
    catch ( InterruptedException e )
       {
       System.out.println( "awakened prematurely" );
       }
    System.out.println("It is dark and spooky...");
    try
       {
       // Sleep at least n milliseconds.
       // 1 millisecond = 1/1000 of a second.
       Thread.sleep( 2000 );
       }
    catch ( InterruptedException e )
       {
       System.out.println( "awakened prematurely" );
       }
    System.out.println("A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and...");
    try
       {
       // Sleep at least n milliseconds.
       // 1 millisecond = 1/1000 of a second.
       Thread.sleep( 2000 );
       }
    catch ( InterruptedException e )
       {
       System.out.println( "awakened prematurely" );
       }

    double friendlyCave = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2);

    if (chosenCave == friendlyCave) {
        System.out.println("Gives you his treasure!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Gobbles you down in one bite!");
    }



}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playAgain = "yes";
    boolean play = true;
    while (play) {
        displayIntro();
        int caveNumber = chooseCave();
        checkCave(caveNumber);
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes or no)");
        playAgain = inner.nextLine();
        if (playAgain == "yes") {
            play = true;
        }
        else {
            play = false;
        }
    }
    inner.close();

}

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You close the second `Scanner` which closes the underlying `InputStream`, therefore the first `Scanner` can no longer read from the same `InputStream` and a `NoSuchElementException` results.

The solution: For console apps, use a single `Scanner` to read from `System.in`.

*Aside:* As stated already, be aware that `Scanner#nextInt` does not consume newline characters. Ensure that these are consumed before attempting to call `nextLine` again by using `Scanner#newLine()`.

See: [Do not create multiple buffered wrappers on a single InputStream](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+InputStream)

Comment: +1, I forgot to mention the multiple Scanners with one input problem.

Comment: Thanks to you and syb0rg. I just had to delete the method with the scanner in it and place the equivalent in the main method. It works! First success in a new programming language... feels really good. :)

Answer (score 13):

The `nextInt()` method leaves the `\n` (end line) symbol and is picked up immediately by `nextLine()`, skipping over the next input.  What you want to do is use `nextLine()` for everything, and parse it later:

```
String nextIntString = keyboard.nextLine(); //get the number as a single line
int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString); //convert the string to an int
```

This is by far the easiest way to avoid problems--don't mix your "next" methods.  Use only `nextLine()` and then parse `int`s or separate words afterwards.

---

Also, make sure you use only one `Scanner` if your are only using one terminal for input.  That could be another reason for the exception.

---

Last note: compare a `String` with the `.equals()` function, not the `==` operator.

```
if (playAgain == "yes"); // Causes problems
if (playAgain.equals("yes")); // Works every time
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I had enough points on here to upvote you. I fixed what you said, and it still didn't work... but the good news is, once I took the scanner out of the method, I was able to just put it all in the main method and it worked fine. Helped with number initializing too. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 5):

simply don't close in

remove `in.close()` from your code.

Comment: This duplicates the accepted answer, but at a much lower quality.

Comment: I was also facing the same problem.. After searching a lot on internet and finally removing in.close() from my code worked for me. That's why I've answered this.

Comment: This answer was really already given, and with a much better explanation.

Comment: @AndrewBarber can you tell me which answers tells to remove in.close(). I know I have not provided any explanation but the answer is right. Accepted answer tells to use only 1 scanner ( which sometimes is not possible ), I have said don't close the scanner at all. There is difference in both answers ( if you read carefully ).

Answer (score 1):

Reimeus is right, you see this because of **in.close** in your **chooseCave()**.
Also, this is wrong.

```
if (playAgain == "yes") {
      play = true;
}
```

You should use equals instead of "==".

```
if (playAgain.equals("yes")) {
      play = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone explained pretty well on it. Let me answer when should this class be used.

**When Should You Use NoSuchElementException?**

Java includes a few different ways to iterate through elements in a collection. The first of these classes, Enumeration, was introduced in `JDK1.0` and is generally considered deprecated in favor of newer iteration classes, like Iterator and ListIterator.

As with most programming languages, the Iterator class includes a `hasNext()` method that returns a boolean indicating if the iteration has anymore elements. If `hasNext()` returns `true`, then the `next()` method will return the next element in the iteration. Unlike Enumeration, Iterator also has a `remove()` method, which removes the last element that was obtained via `next()`.

While Iterator is generalized for use with all collections in the `Java Collections Framework`, `ListIterator` is more specialized and only works with List-based collections, like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, and so forth. However, `ListIterator` adds even more functionality by allowing iteration to traverse in both directions via `hasPrevious()` and `previous()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the earlier comment by someone else:

> You close the second Scanner which closes the underlying InputStream,
> therefore the first Scanner can no longer read from the same
> InputStream and a NoSuchElementException results.
>
> The solution: For console apps, use a single Scanner to read from
> System.in.
>
> Aside: As stated already, be aware that Scanner#nextInt does not
> consume newline characters. Ensure that these are consumed before
> attempting to call nextLine again by using Scanner#newLine().
>
> See: Do not create multiple buffered wrappers on a single InputStream

I have came up with this solution. Perhaps this will help someone:

the following code WORKS:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static String func(Scanner in) {
        String input = "";
        in = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
        input = in.next();
        System.out.println("UserInput: " + input);

        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;
        s = func(in);
        System.out.println("Main: " + s);

        s = func(in);
        System.out.println("Main: " + s);
    }
}
```

and the following code WILL NOT WORK. this output the same problem as the thread:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static String func() {
        String input = "";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("UserInput: " + input);

        input = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("UserInput: " + input);

        s.close();

        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s;
        s = func();
        System.out.println("Main: " + s);

        s = func();
        System.out.println("Main: " + s);
    }
}
```