# Adding Int Values to a 2-D Array

Tags: java, int, multidimensional-array

I have this code and it prints a 4x4 matrix with all values of 0. How do I add code to input values from a file?

The `matdata1.txt` file reads:

> 4 4
>
> 1 2 3 4
>
> 2 4 6 8
>
> 2 4 6 8
>
> 3 2 3 4

Here is my code:

```
File f = new File( args[0]);
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

int row = s.nextInt();
int col = s.nextInt();
int [] [] mat = new int [row] [col];



for(int i =0; i < row; i++)
{
    for( int j =0; j < col; j++)
    {
        System.out.print (mat[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println( );
}
```

Comment: You haven't written any code which actually adds elements to the array. You're quite close, however, so give it a shot!

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to implement, give it a shot and then come back when you have further trouble. SO are here to help once you have tried something, but we cant just go giving you the answers.

Comment: A few clues though; you should probably use a `BufferedReader` to read the file line by line, and see whether you can parse it appropriately.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl - This looks like a homework problem, so it's probably OK for him to assume he can just call `nextInt()` on the scanner over and over again until he gets all of the expected input.

Comment: You should do `s.nextLine()` and parse that into an `int`.  That isn't a solution to your problem, just a suggestion to improve your code and possibly prevent problems later.

Comment: @syb0rg - I think using `nextLine()` would be overcomplicating the problem. If the instructor (I'm assuming this is homework) wanted them to actually parse the input, they wouldn't have needed to include the matrix dimensions in the file. I think he can just assume all calls to `nextInt()` will be successful if he reads `row*col` ints.

Comment: yes this is homework, im not going to lie and i dont expect to be given the answer. ive just been doing a lot of looking for my problem and my teacher hasnt said anything about BUfferedReader which leads me to think id need either a while or for loop

Comment: @DaoWen You are right of course, but say the OP wants to get a `String` from the `Scanner` later on.  If he leaves those `nextInt()`s in there instead of doing what I suggested, he most likely will get a `NoSuchElementException`. See from one of my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception/15398752#15398752).

Answer (score 0):

You **already have** code to input values from a file!

I've added some comments to the code you posted:

```
File f = new File( args[0]); // Get the input file
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);  // Open the file with a Scanner (a basic parsing tool)

int row = s.nextInt(); // Read the 1st number from the file as row count
int col = s.nextInt(); // Read the 2nd number from the file as column count
int [] [] mat = new int [row] [col]; // Use the row and column counts you read for the matrix dimensions
```

Look at the documentation for [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information.

Of particular interest is the [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method used in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
int row = Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());
int col = Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());
int elem = 0;
for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
  tk = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
  for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
    elem = Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());
    arr[i][j] = elem;
  }
}
```