# NoSuchElementException Java Scanner *not closing scanner*

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was just testing out Java and got this error with a basic Scanner interaction.

```
Value x: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:10)
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x;
        System.out.println("Value x: ");
        x = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(x);
     }
}
```

Comment: And what did you use as your input? Not a double?

Comment: @user1071777 In that case it should throw input mismatch Exception .

Comment: try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15398752/1066779)

Comment: Just write `x = input.nextDouble();` x2 times and see.Just curious

Comment: @joeyrohan, it'll still give me the error at the first input.nextDouble().

Comment: @Rembo, I saw that question before and tried following the solution there but it still didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that there's a `double` to read, it's a good idea to also pull the invalid data -

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double x;
System.out.println("Value x: ");
while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
  if (!input.hasNext()) {
    System.err.println("no more input");
    System.exit(1);
  }
  System.out.println(input.next() + ": is not a double, please enter a double");
}
x = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: I tried that too. It just prints out "no more input" and quits.

Comment: @VikramMehta Is this all that's in your `main()` method? Are you using a real Java developer environment, or are you using an online tool? If it says "no more input" above, then the `Scanner` is incapable of reading `System.in`. Usually, that's because you have closed `System.in`

Comment: Ah, it might be because I am using an online editor. I can't have a real JDE on this system. That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what input you supply to get this error but I can imagine it occurs when you pipe some other input string to this program, or if you type ctrl-z in your console.

Anyway, what happens is that you don't supply input to the scanner.

Try verifying the input with `.hasNext()`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x;
        System.out.println("Value x: ");
        if (input.hasNext()) {
          x = input.nextDouble();
          System.out.println(x);
        } else {
          System.out.println("You didn't supply a value for x...");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: also: checking if you actually get a double can be a good idea (see the other answer)

Comment: That's a compile error, not a runtime error. When I used hasNext(), it just skips the stuff inside the brackets.

Comment: @VikramMehta I think you are missing something.Is that all the code? Please give all the details.

Comment: @VikramMehta obviously.. Because you're not supplying any input to `nextDouble()`. In fact, that is what the `hasNext()` is for, to prevent the runtime error. I will edit the code to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, it might be because I am using an online editor. I can't have a real JDE on this system. That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On running the same program online: http://www.jdoodle.com/

I got the same `NoSuchElementException`.It is recommended to [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) JDK 8 and try running same program.

Online editors may work differently (in some cases) so you wont get the desired result.

However, in the above link if you give stdin inputs before hand, it works fine.

Comment: Ah, it might be because I am using an online editor. I can't have a real JDE on this system. That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :) If the answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the green tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

It's Look Like a problem in your standard input. Try to put this line above the scanner to make sure you can read standard input. Then run again type some letters and check whether you can read from standard input.

```
System.out.println((char)System.in.read());
```

If this line also gives same exception its a problem with standard input. Try re installing JVM with default settings.

PS: Your code works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the scanner tries to get a number from the input stream when nothing has been entered.

The way to solve this is to wait for Scanner.hasNextDouble() to be true so that it tries to read the number input after it comes in.

```
while(!input.hasNextDouble()) { }

x = input.nextDouble();
```