# java.util.NoSuchElementException using only one Scanner

Tags: java, csv, nosuchelementexception

So, I am trying to read contents of a .csv file using Scanner and every time I get the error the title says.

At first, I read on the [Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception) that it was due to the fact that you must not have more than one Scanner instances in your project because they can consume the input, so I used BufferedReader to scan the user choice and Scanner to open the .csv file.

Now I get the error again, having only one Scanner Instance and I do not know why this is happening.

**Question.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Question {
    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("\nEnter your choice :\n");
        System.out.println("1 - Load Hotels and Reservations from file");
        System.out.println("\nEnter \"1\"");
        int choice = 1;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (choice == 1)
            loadOption();
    }

    public static void loadOption() {
        Scanner scan;
        ArrayList<Hotel> hotel = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
            scan = new Scanner(new File("data1.csv"));
            scan.useDelimiter(";");
            int column = 1;
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                scan.next();
                if (column == 1)
                    hotel.id = scan.next();
                if (column == 2)
                    hotel.name = scan.next();
                if (column == 3)
                    hotel.star = scan.next();
                if (column == 4)
                    hotel.rooms = scan.next();
            }
            System.out.print("Files Succesfully Loaded!!!\n");
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question obj = new Question();
        obj.menu();
    }

};
```

**Hotel.java**

```
public class Hotel extends Question {
    String id, star, rooms, name;

    public Hotel() {
    } // constructor
};
```

This is how I compile them :

```
javac Hotel.java
javac Question.java
java Question
```

The exact error is like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Question.loadOption(Question.java:43)
    at Question.menu(Question.java:27)
    at Question.main(Question.java:62)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String csvFile = "data1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
     ArrayList <Hotel> hotel = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Hotel hotelob = new Hotel();
            // use comma as separator
            String[] hotelproperties = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            //setting properties to hotelobject
            hotelob.id = hotelproperties[0];  
            hotelob.name =hotelproperties[1];
            hotelob.star =hotelproperties[2];
            hotelob.rooms =hotelproperties[3];
            //adding the object to arraylist 
            hotel.add(hotelob);  
        }
```

you can do this very easily if you use a `bufferedreader` this way you can handle multiple lines and at the same time you can `split` the data from each line easily. put this code into your `loadoption` method this might help.

Answer (score 4):

You check `hasNext()`, but then you call `next()` twice. So the second call is unchecked. Even worse, the first call is not needed and has no effect. You also don't increment your `column` variable.

Try this:

```
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
scan = new Scanner(new File("data1.csv"));
scan.useDelimiter(";");
int column=1; 
while (scan.hasNext()) {
  //scan.next(); this is not needed
  if (column == 1)
    hotel.id = scan.next();
  if (column == 2)
    hotel.name = scan.next();
  if (column == 3)
    hotel.star = scan.next();
  if (column == 4)
    hotel.rooms = scan.next();
  //this is needed as well:
  column++;
}
System.out.print("Files Succesfully Loaded!!!\n");
scan.close();
```

Note: you still only create one instance of Hotel.

Comment: remove the `column++` at the end  and add  `column = 1;`  this wont work after the first line

Comment: Of course this wont work after the first line as I said in the note at the bottom. But the ``column++`` is needed in each line. What purpose does ``column = 1`` serve after you read a single value?

Comment: bt at somepoint `column will be equal to 5` then what happens

Comment: @Priyamal nothing will happen. But your suggestion is to just assume that the next value from the scanner should be treated as column 1. Multiple lines need to be handled correctly, which doesnt happen in OP's code at all.