# Java; As soon as I encounter an input I get "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm making a very basic database management program, I've got a scanner for name and value working fine in one class(Account.java),

```
public static void createNewAccount() {

    Scanner newScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String inputName = newScan.nextLine();
    name = inputName;
    System.out.print("Enter the initial value: ");
    double inputBalance = newScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("... successfully created new account.");

    keyScan.close();


    Account newAccount = new Account(inputName, inputBalance);

}
```

Debugging this little bit works fine, but when I jump back into my other class (Management.java) and hit my switch statement I'm stuck with this error, and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else (Lots of people get the same error, but for different reasons it seems?)

```
...
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Account.createAccount();
//Debugging statement #1 here works fine, can access other Class
do{
        /*
        Menu Options
        */
        System.out.println(">> Select your option (1-6)");
        choice = in.nextInt();

//Debugging statement #2 here doesn't display, this is where the error hits.

    switch (choice) {
         ... Cases
        }
```

This is the console output:

```
>> Select your option (1-6)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at Management.main(Management.java:30)
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening because I've got another scanner that works perfectly fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you close a `Scanner` it also closes the underlying `InputStream`. So if you create a scanner using `System.in` at an earlier point in the program and then close that scanner, it would close `System.in`.

Once an inputstream has been closed it can no longer be read from and attempts to do so will cause a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Holy crap, so I just closed my other scanners too early?

Aaand I just went and commented them out, it works perfectly. Thank you sir!!