# How java.util.NoSuchElementException (basic program)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

java.util.NoSuchElementException problem... I used two scanners

```
scanbud()
```

and

```
scabudrad()
```

Comment: Add the ***complete*** stacktrace as ***text***.

Comment: You give us 225 lines of code .. with tons of useless, lines, please edit and remove some

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: dont close the scanner, try again, share the lessons learned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the answer itself. Instead, post it as answer or mark one of the existing answers as accepted (like you already did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is here:

```
scanbudRad.close();
```

you are using multiple instances of the scanner, _BUT as soon as you closes  a scanner, that instance close under the hood too the input stream which is shared between all other remaining instances... after that, trying to read /get something from an scanner object with a **InputStream** closed throws the exception.

Comment: so should i put only 1 scanner through out? I read a page saying the close and open scanner with each logical block of code