# file.hasNext() dont stop loop while

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a txt file following that code:

```
static public void main(String[] args) throws  FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Leo\\Downloads\\Ler Arquivo\\Iris.txt");
        Scanner texto = new Scanner(file) .useDelimiter(",|\n");
        Float[] sepal_length = new Float[1000];
        int i=4;
        int j=0;
        while(texto.hasNext()){
            if(i%4==0){
           System.out.println(texto.next());
            j++;
            }
            i++;
            texto.next();
}  
    }
```

My txt file is like that:

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,setosa
```

I' ve created array to receives only sepal_length from file. So, I' ve created a variable i for count each 4th position of each line. When I use the variable i to count the data position, I find that error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at ler.arquivo.Arquivo.main(Arquivo.java:22)
C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

When I don' t use the variable i, just for print on console my file, my code perfectly work. 
You guys may help me? How can I separate each data to my array? I'm a beginner in Java.

Comment: You are calling `next()` multiple times.

Comment: I need to call next() every time to catch each delimiter, don' t I?

Comment: @LeonardoCampadelli Save the result of texto.next() in a variable and use that variable in that context

Comment: Why you increase i variable?

Comment: I increase the i variable because the 4th position of each line have the data witch I want (sepal_length).

Comment: Check this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: For the second "texto.next()" use if (texto.hasNext()) and see what happens.

Comment: @M.Afrashteh - Thanks man, its worked!!! Why my while dont verify my condition? I must to use a if(texto.hasNext())?

Comment: Your "While" only check one "texto.next()". When your "if" statement is true you have two "texto.next()" that first one checked by "While" condition but second not.

Answer (score 0):

When `if` statement is `true` you have two `texto.next()` lines of code in a `While` loop that the first one checked by `While` condition but second not checked by any coded control.