# Young Physicist problem on Code Forces(JAVA) Runtime Error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am new to CodeForces, when i run this code in NetBeans its works correctly but when I submit it on CodeForces it gives me Runtime error on test 1. what is the wrong? This is the [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/69/A)

It is my code:

```
package cw;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CW {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ourNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        int VasyaNumber = ourNumber.nextInt();
        String result = Vasya(VasyaNumber);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

    public static String Vasya(int number) {
        String saying;
        int ours = 0;
        int resultone = 0;
        int resulttwo = 0;
        int resultthree = 0;
        while (ours < number) {
            Scanner yourNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = yourNumber.nextInt();
            int y = yourNumber.nextInt();
            int z = yourNumber.nextInt();
            resultone += x;
            resulttwo += y;
            resultthree += z;
            ours += 1;
        }
        if (resultone == 0 && resulttwo == 0 && resultthree == 0) {
            saying = "YES";
        } else {
            saying = "NO";
        }
        return saying;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're beginner , so i have some tips for you.

**1.** Have multiple scanners (on same stream) is a very bad practice, because scanners consume the stream they share , For more info: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception/15398862#15398862).

**The solution :**  For console apps, use a single `Scanner` to read from `System.in`.

**2.** After solve the problem in your laptop , then you have to comment this line `package cw;` to submit it to online judge , otherwise , will give you this Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class CW
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CW
```

**Updated**

I have modified your code and it's worked now :

```
//package cw; // you must comment this line because will give you error if upload it to online Judge
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;


public class CW 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner ourNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        int VasyaNumber = ourNumber.nextInt();
        // Updated , send scanner object as Parameter 
        String result = Vasya(VasyaNumber , ourNumber);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String Vasya(int number , Scanner yourNumber) 
    {
        String saying;
        int ours = 0;
        int resultone = 0;
        int resulttwo = 0;
        int resultthree = 0;
        while (ours < number) 
        {
            int x = yourNumber.nextInt();
            int y = yourNumber.nextInt();
            int z = yourNumber.nextInt();
            resultone += x;
            resulttwo += y;
            resultthree += z;
            ours += 1;
        }
        
        if (resultone == 0 && resulttwo == 0 && resultthree == 0) 
        {
            saying = "YES";
        } 
        else 
        {
            saying = "NO";
        }
        return saying;
    }

}
```

**Modification**

**1.** Comment this line `package cw;`, otherwise will give you error as i mentioned before.

**2.** Passing Scanner object as a parameter to `Vasya` function.

**3.** `Vasya` function have two parameters now. `int` and `Scanner`. In your case, first parameter `VasyaNumber` and second parameter `Scanner` called `ourNumber`.

**4.** you don't need this line of code anymore `Scanner yourNumber = new Scanner(System.in);` but why ? because you already declared it in your `main()`

Hope that helps you, Good Luck and wish you all the best!