# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException When trying to get String input

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

In my java code when i am trying to get input as String So Scanner.next() and when i run it `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`
this is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    static int choice;
    static Thread t;
    static boolean isCompleteLoading;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println();
        mainMenu ();
    }

    static void Register () throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Student student1 = new Student();

        System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t       WELCOME TO MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t     ------------------------");

        System.out.print("\t\tEnter Your Name: ");
        student1.studentName = input.next();
        System.out.print("\t\tEnter Your Phone Number: ");
        student1.phoneNumber = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("\t\tEnter Your address: ");
        student1.address = input.next();
        System.out.print("\t\tEnter Your school name: ");
        student1.schoolName = input.next();
        System.out.print("\t\tHow do you wish to pay");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t\t 1.Full");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t\t 2.Half");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tEnter Your choice: ");
        student1.paymentType = input.nextInt();
        processing();

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Person.txt"));
        out.writeObject(student1);
        input.close();
    }

    public static void processing() {
        t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.print("Processing---------");
                for(int i = 0;i <= 100;i++){
                    if(i < 10){
                        System.out.print(i+"%");
                        System.out.print("\b\b");
                    }
                    else if(i >= 10 && i <= 99){
                        System.out.print(i+"%");
                        System.out.print("\b\b\b");
                    }
                    else{
                     System.out.println(i+"%");
                     isCompleteLoading = true;
                    }
                    try {
                        t.sleep(100);
                    } catch(Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
  }

    public static void mainMenu () throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t ANATHA STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
        System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t       WELCOME TO MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\t 1.Register New Student");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t 2.Find Student");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t\t Enter Your choice: ");

        choice = in.nextInt();

        in.close();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                Register ();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at App.Register(App.java:27)
    at App.mainMenu(App.java:90)
    at App.main(App.java:15)
```

why is this error occurred ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: no i use a single Scanner object for all of inputs but it didnt solved

Comment: I tried your code with single Scanner instance and it is working. Could you update the question with what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Register()` function, you try to create a Scanner on `System.in`. However, before calling `Register()` in `mainMenu()`, you close the Scanner created at the beginning of `mainMenu()`. Due to how `InputStreams` in Java work, this also closes `System.in`, therefore trying to create a new Scanner on it doesn't work. This is why it's best to only have one Scanner for command line programs - if you need it in multiple functions, you can either make it a static variable or pass it down as an argument for those functions.